# Not able to access Spring boot application.properties

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, application.properties

I am trying to access `application.properties` values in spring boot application's service class. But every time value is null, so it throws `NullPointException`. I can get the right value for port in controller class(if i add `@Autowired` in controller) but not in service class. What changes are required to make this properties available through out the application?

**Controller** looks like:

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

MyService ss = new MyService();


 @RequestMapping(value = "/myapp/abcd", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = {"application/json"})
    public ResponseMessage sendPostMethod(@RequestBody String request) {
        log.debug(" POST Request received successfully; And request body is:"+ request);

        ResponseMessage response = ss.processRequest(request);
        return response;

    }

}
```

And **Service** class is:

```
@Service
public class MyService {

    private ApplicationProperties p;

    @Autowired 
    public setProps(ApplicationProperties config) {
           this.p = config;
    }

    public ResponseMessage processRequest(String request) {
          System.out.println("Property value is:"+ p.getPort());
    }

}
```

**ApplicationProperties.java** looks like:

```
@Component
@Getter
@Setter
@ConfigurationProperties
public class ApplicationProperties {

     String port;
}
```

Finally, `application.properties` file has:

```
port=1234
```

I have even tried passing `ApplicationProperties` instance from controller to service's default constructor, but it did not work. When I debug, value persist while application startup, but when I make a rest web service POST call, it is null.

Comment: This line is the issue. `MyService ss = new MyService();` you should autowire it not create using `new`

Comment: You mean "@Autowired MyService ss;" ?

Comment: Yes. If you create an object with new . It is not a spring bean

Comment: Right. Thanks...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller `MyController`, you have to inject the service, replacing:

```
MyService ss = new MyService();
```

by:

```
@Autowired
MyService ss;
```

Also, instead of your `ApplicationProperties` class, you can use `@Value` annotation, from **Spring**, to load properties from `application.properties` file. Take a look at this code:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
// ...

@Service
public class MyService {

    @Value("${port}")
    private String port;

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue but for other reasons.
For me the solution was to add spring. before each parameter in application.properties.
So e.g. "spring.flyway.user=root".